# Disable podcast chapters on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, podcasts

I like to listen to podcasts on my iPhone, and there's one feature that really bugs me: when a podcast has chapters, it's impossible to see how far you are into the podcast, how much is left, or to scrub between chapters. Is there a way to disable this feature?

[image]

Comment: Do you not get that info from the `-X:XX` time remaining?

Comment: @Nathan The X:XX time remaining is for the chapter, not the entire podcast

Comment: Does that number change if you tap it?

Answer (score 2):

The button just to the right of the podcast title will show you all the chapters, let you jump between them, and show the length of time in each.

The only way I know to show how much time is left in total is to hit the Back arrow, which brings you back to the podcast listing. This screen will show you how much time is left in the podcast.